# Собственные функции для работы с STL

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, stl

Как можно создать шаблонную функцию, которая будет работать с любым **STL**-контейнером? Не понимаю, как должна выглядеть сигнатура функции и как получить `iterator` на начало контейнера, чтобы начать его перебор. Хотелось бы, чтобы конечная функция в коде могла применятся, к примеру, так же как и `std::sort(vector.begin(), vector.end(), comparator)`

Comment: ¿Ну а почему бы тогда не сделать ее по образцу std::sort?

Comment: Чтобы совсем с любым - надо очень непритязательный итератор... И, соответственно, использовать перегрузку для разных типов итераторов. `template<typename Itor> void func(Itor begin, Itor end)...` - примерно так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, конечно, зависит от того, что делает твоя функция.
Если это, например, сортировка, то тут свои моменты:

1. map и set сортировать не нужно, они уже отсортированы по ключам, так что для них не получится сделать такую функцию
2. Для вектора, например, нужны итераторы типа RandomIt (random access iterator - итератор с произвольным доступом, то есть тот, к которому можно прибавить любое целое число и получить другой итератор, например, `someVector.begin() + 5` ошибкой не будет)
   Подробнее о категориях итераторов почитай, например, тут https://ci-plus-plus-snachala.ru/?p=298

Но если тебе прям нужно очень универсальное что-то (ну чисто для понимания), да ещё с неким функциональным объектом (в сорте это comparator), тогда вот пример, где condition типа PrintCondition является неким функциональным объектом (можно вызвать в виде condition ()), определяющим условие для вывода элемента контейнера. Данная функция просто выводит любой контейнер STL, поддерживающий концепцию итераторов (с неким условием):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <typename First, typename Second>
ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const pair<First, Second>& pairData) {
    out << "{" << pairData.first << ", " << pairData.second << "}";
    return out;
}

template <typename Iterator, typename PrintCondition>
void PrintContainer(Iterator begin, Iterator end, PrintCondition condition) {
    if (begin == end) {
        cout << "Контейнер пуст" << endl;
        return;
    }

    cout << "{";
    bool first = true;

    for (auto it = begin; it != end; it++) {
        if (condition(*it)) {
            if (!first) {
                cout << ", ";
            }
            first = false;
            cout << *it;
        }
    }
    cout << "}" << endl;
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");

    vector exampleVector = {-17, 15, 54, 0, 124, 997, 901}; // Можно явно не инстанцировать тип шаблона (не указывать в угловых скобках)
    cout << "Вектор: ";
    PrintContainer(exampleVector.begin(), exampleVector.end(), [](int num) { // Вывод всех чётных значений
        return num % 2 == 0;
    });
    exampleVector.clear();
    cout << "Пустой вектор: ";
    PrintContainer(exampleVector.begin(), exampleVector.end(), [](int) {return true;});

    map<int, int> exampleMap = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, -2}, {-5, 0}, {-17, -16}};
    cout << "Мэп: ";
    PrintContainer(exampleMap.begin(), exampleMap.end(), [](pair<int, int> data) { // Вывод значений мэпа с положительными
        return data.first > 0 && data.second % 2 == 0;                             // ключами и чётными значениями
    });

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
Вектор: {54, 0, 124}
Пустой вектор: Контейнер пуст
Мэп: {{1, 2}, {3, -2}}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Спасибо, функция PrintContainer именно то, что мне нужно :)